# lubuntu 14.10 does not boot (DVD nor USB)

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I recently purchased the Linux pro magazine edition for January 2015 sold in Montreal, QC. containing a double sided DVD with ubuntu 14.10 & lubuntu 14.10 in it.

Though I have been able to install -and use Ubuntu 14.04 on both my laptops by downloading the image from ubuntu.com (I even tried mint 17 on one of them, but did not like the interface, so switched back to ubuntu) I am light years away from being a linux pro. Nevertheless, I got the magazine because of the included disk.

I have tried to install the lubuntu distro several -I mean like 6 or 7- times by doing these two things:

*1* booting from the DVD

*2* booting from a live usb.

The ​​​​problem starts at the Boot Menu. If I select number 2 (USB) or number 3 (ODD), the following screen is a message saying "Start PXE over IPv4, Press ESC to EXIT...". So I go back, select number 4 (LAN) and then I have to choose between IPv4 and IPv6. Both options simply start my existing Ubuntu 14.04

What am I doing wrong?

All this is on a Toshiba Satellite C50D-A running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

After analyse your problem I think answer is below

- PXE over IP is the option to boot from a network source and is a setting in the BIOS.
- Press F2  go into BIOS settings.
- In the NIC settings you should be able to turn off PXE boot altogether as this would only be used on corporate networks.
- In the boot options you can make the 1st boot device the Flesh-drive or CD/DVD what ever device you like to first boot.
- Or else you just press f12 or f10 to boot menu and select the device which device through you want to format(installation of Ubuntu).

*If any problem with this answer please comment me....:)

Comment: My problen now is I can't find the NIC settings... F2 does nothing.  I use F12 to access the menu, but I don't see NIC settings @virbhadrasin

Comment: I am glade to answer you :)

Comment: My problen now is I cant fin the NIC settings... F2 does nothing.  I use F12 to access the menu, but I dont see NIC settings @virbhadrasin

Comment: ok than you are in BIOS ?

Comment: if you not find the NIC setting then you find network boot disable

Comment: When I try to go to BIOS only System Time, System Date and Language can be accessed (lines 1, 2 and 10). System BIOS Version has a different color and cant be selected. *** https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_cP10nFSiT3X3ZwTF80dG5ENTA&authuser=0

Comment: when you press left arrow -> key then any thing not doing ?

Comment: The arrows only navigate the top menu, not the submenus

Comment: Yes in Toshiba BIOS, you need to press the right arrow to get to the boot tab as seen in this picture (is sony but insyde H20BIOS is setup the same). http://i75.servimg.com/u/f75/11/84/18/82/photo-10.jpg It's either BOOT or ADVANCED that has the option.

Comment: @carlos it's on the boot tab, here's the image http://s7.postimage.org/3sh9egs8r/DSCN0778.jpg

Comment: yes its in the boot menu,do it ?

Comment: You are do it as you say ? means solve your problem ?

Comment: press -> for the navigation menu and ^ and \/ for goes into the menu and change the boot order.

Comment: the right arrow takes me to the boot menu, yes... but if I go to "3. ODD" and press enter or F10 Ubuntu 14.04 boots from the HD, not Lubuntu from the DVD. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_cP10nFSiT3alQ3blFCLXR5MjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In that option use F5 or F6 and come to at first position "ODD"

Comment: Do it successfully ?

Comment: 3. ODD is finally on top and it is 1. ODD... after pressing enter the boot starts from the HD https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_cP10nFSiT3UjgycjdPTEs4dGM&authuser=0 I am guessing the DVD is defective.

Comment: After come to ODD at top you just save your changes using F10 ?

Comment: I saved using F10. Did not work. Thanks anyway @Virbhadrasinh

Comment: ok if any problem feel free to say....:)